# Add Full Resource to TastyPie Action Response

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have the following AuthResource defined in my api.py. It accepts a post request to the /auth/login action and then returns the user their ApiKey to be used on the rest of my resources which have ApiKeyAuthentication set.

```
class AuthResource(Resource):
class Meta:
    authorization = Authorization()
    resource_name = 'auth'
    list_allowed_methods = ['post']

def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login")
    ]

def login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    email = data.get('email', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')

    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            data = {'success': True, 'api_key': ApiKey.objects.get(user=user).key}
            return self.create_response(request, data)
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {'success': False, 'reason': 'account_disabled'}, HttpForbidden)
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {'success': False, 'reason': 'incorrect_login'}, HttpUnauthorized)
```

This works just as I like it but I'd like to take but I'd like to take it a step further and have this login action also return a serialized user object. When I modify the code like so:

```
if user.is_active:
            data = {'success': True, 'api_key': ApiKey.objects.get(user=user).key}
            data['user'] = user
            return self.create_response(request, data)
```

Unfortunately I get the following response to my POST request in Postman:

```
{"api_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "success": true, "user": "FirstName LastName"}
```

I know this is the value of my user model's `__unicode__` function, but what I really want is the full serialized object. Something more like:

```
{"api_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "success": true, "user": {'first_name': 'FirstName', 'last_name': 'LastName', 'email': 'email@example.com'}}
```

Any ideas? I guess I don't have to do it this way, I could just have the client submit another get request to the proper UserResource using the newly acquired ApiKey but it seems like such obviously low-hanging fruit in terms of optimization. I welcome any and all thoughts/best practices when it comes to API design.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but I'd like to recommend http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ which will allow you to easily achieve what you want, and you'll love the framework.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @orokusaki, I'm a little far in to switch but I think I will go with django-restframework for the next project as it seems to be a more django-styled framework. I came across tastypie first and it seemed to have enough critical mass to make it worth learning.